# How to add check for list object in predicate Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, predicate, specifications

I have one user entity in that I have a list of roles, Now I want to fetch user list by specific list of the user using Java specification and predicate. Can anyone help me out? For reference below is the code snnipet.

```
public List<Users> findByPagingCriteria(SearchModel searchModel, Pageable pageable) {
        Page page = userRepository.findAll(new Specification<Users>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Users> root, javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                    CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                if (searchModel.getName() != null) {
                    predicates.add(cb.or(cb.like(root.get("firstName"), "%" + searchModel.getName() + "%"),
                            cb.like(root.get("lastName"), "%" + searchModel.getName() + "%")));
                }
                if (searchModel.getId() != null) {
                    predicates
                            .add(cb.and(cb.equal(root.get("adminDetails").get("adminUniqueId"), searchModel.getId())));
                }
                if (searchModel.getRole() != null && searchModel.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {
                    List<Role> roles = Arrays.asList(Role.builder().name("ROLE_ADMIN").build());

                    predicates.add(cb.and(cb.equal(root.get("roles"), roles)));
                }
                return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            }
        }, pageable);

        page.getTotalElements(); // get total elements
        page.getTotalPages(); // get total pages
        return page.getContent(); // get List of Employee
    }
```

Check the roles section, in that I have passed the list of ADMIN role. But while running it throws me an error saying,

> java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 4

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but I wouldn't use `cb.equal(root.get("roles"), roles))` to compare collections. You would better off using `cb.isMember`.

Comment: @HopeyOne Now error is not throwing but no record is coming from DB. Any Idea?

Comment: You can [log] (https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot) your SQL queries generated by spring-boot-data with the `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` property. You could then try to debug the query against your underlying data source.